Help with Proof Related to Space of Codimension One
Let $H$ be a infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $\{e_{i}\}$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$ be an orthogonal basis of it. Let the span of $e_{1}$ be $U$ and $span(e_{i}:i>1)=V$, so $U^{\perp}=\overline{V}\neq V$.Let $E=span(e_{i}:i\in\mathbb{N})$. Clearly $\overline{E\cap\overline{V}}=\overline{V}$.
Now let $\overline{V}^{c}$ be set complement of $\overline{V}$, so $\overline{V}\cup \overline{V}^{c}=H$ with $\overline{V}\cap \overline{V}^{c}$ being empty set. Now $E\cap\overline{V}\cup E\cap\overline{V}^{c}=E$. Taking closure of both sides, we have $\overline{V}\cup\overline{E\cap\overline{V}^{c}}=\overline{E}=H$. Since $\overline{V}\cap \overline{V}^{c}$ is empty, $\overline{V}^{c}\cap\overline{E\cap\overline{V}^{c}}=\overline{V}^{c}$, so $\overline{V}^{c}\subset\overline{E\cap\overline{V}^{c}}$. As the closure of set is equal to interior of it union boundary of it, and $\overline{V}$ is closed, so $\overline{V}^{c}\subset int(E\cap\overline{V}^{c})$.
Now $int(E\cap\overline{V}^{c})\subset int(E)\cap int(\overline{V}^{c})$. As $E$ being proper subspace of $H$, $E^{c}$ is dense and thus $int(E)$ is empty. So $int(E\cap\overline{V}^{c})$ is empty and $\overline{V}^{c}$ is empty, which is impossible as $e_{1}\in\overline{V}^{c}$.
So what are the mistakes in the above proof? The conclusion is clearly wrong while every steps seems right to me. Can anyone provide some insight to me?

Sorry, just edited.

Why is $\bar V{}^c$ empty?

@AnneB Thanks. I started at the end :)

Let $$F:=E\cap\overline V^c.$$
The wrong step is when going from
$\overline V^c\subset\overline F$ to $\overline V^c\subset\operatorname{int}F$.
$$\overline V^c=\{x\in H\mid x\cdot e_1\ne0\},$$
$$F=\{x\in E\mid x\cdot e_1\ne0\},$$
$$\overline F=H,\quad\operatorname{int}F=\varnothing.$$
